# Automatic Data transfer in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, transfer

I have created three lists with similar fields in Excel. I would like to set these lists up so that when I input Data into my master list in a given field it will automatically transfer to the same field on my other lists. How would I do this. I have searched for an answer, but I have found none. I am new to Excel, but I do have programming experience.

Comment: How are the other lists different from the master list? Are you adding rows, deleting rows, changing existing values?  Is the order of the various lists important?

Answer (score 0):

### I think the  =VLOOKUP() function is what you are looking for.

I have fixed adressess($) and used a column choser to be able to easily change column information, and also to just copy or strech your table into new columns or rows whithout needing to update formulas.

### [=VLOOKUP() http://img638.imageshack.us/img638/2596/unledjyl.png](http://img638.imageshack.us/img638/2596/unledjyl.png)